# Ionic iOS 11 build error with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I've tried every possible solution I could find for this cryptic error and no luck.

In my Ionic project, I've added the platform, but when I go to run the project in the simulator through Xcode, I get this error:

`error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-aedfralrxnetyceopmcioxkdhsxh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/ProjectName": No such file or directory`

Not sure where else to turn other than here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is error you get in browser when you run command  "ionic serve --lab"  ?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run it in the browser.

Comment: have you tried `rm -rf platforms` followed by `ionic cordova build ios` to see if some files were left around?

Comment: Did you change your project name?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `DerivedData/` from old Xcode.

Go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and remove your project:

```
$ rm -rf /ProjectName-aedfralrxnetyceopmcioxkdhsxh
```

Next, in Xcode run clear -> build

---

Also check that your Simulators are up to date

Comment: I did those steps and am still getting the debug map error :/

Answer (score 0):

From the Xcode do following two things  might solve your problem.

1. Product -> Clean and build folder
2. Go to `finder -> library -> Developer -> Xcode -> Derived data` delete
   that folder